# Test value fist character of string - C#

Tags: c#, razor

in one of our templates for report printing there is the following code:

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetModel.Belongings))
{
    description = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
        description,
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) ? "" : ", ",
        assetModel.Belongings);
}
```

I would like to test the first character of the Belongings field. if it IS NOT a "," then the code above should be used but if it IS a "," the code should be like:

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetModel.Belongings))
{
    description = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
        description,
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) ? "" : "",
        assetModel.Belongings);
}
```

Please help, how can I test this value of the first character?

Comment: you can use [String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method [StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) is self-explaining:

```
if (description.StarstWith(","))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is the solution I was looking for, and this is the result.  Sorry, can't get the code shown in the right way.  

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetModel.Belongings))
    {if (assetModel.Belongings.StartsWith(","))
{
        description = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
            description,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) ? "" : "",
            assetModel.Belongings);
    }
else
{
        description = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
            description,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) ? "" : ", ",
            assetModel.Belongings);
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

Use [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the index of the `,` character is 0, meaning it's at the start of the string.

```
if (description.IndexOf(',') == 0)
{
    // description starts with a ,
}
```

Comment: It should work, but IndexOf isn't build for this purpose. In my optinion StartsWith() would be better in this context.

Comment: Searching whole string instead of just checking `description[0]==','`?

Comment: @Jannik true, didn't think of `StartsWith` until after I posted.

Comment: @Steve I feel you, I was about to post a substring-alternative, well, there are many different roads to reach the same goal.